# How to open a .txt file and implement it into my program

Tags: python

```
try:
    open_pre = open((preferences.txt), "r")
    open_pre = open_pre.read()
    open_pre.close()
    print(open_pre)
except:
    print("Could not load preferences.txt")
```

I have a try and except where i try to read a text file with my settings in it and implement it into my program but every time i get the except error "Could not load preferences.txt". How do i store the file in a variable or do i have to read each line independently.

Here is what i am trying to load

```
# Password protects the program when opened ('True' or 'False')
password_protected = True
user_password = "123"

# Program presets (Ex. ip_preset = "198.148.81.137")
ip_preset = ""
port_preset = ""
hostname_preset = ""
message_preset = ""

# Sends a message in each socket sent ('True' or 'False')
send_message = True

# Auto-generate a message from the internal library. ('True' or 'False')
autogen_msg = True
```

Comment: You're swallowing essential information by consuming the exception -- how do you expect folks to know what problem you have unless we actually get *the specific problem* emitted in your logs? There's a reason pychecker, pylint, &c. will flag a bare `except:` as an antipattern; *don't do it*. If you *must* hide exceptions, at least using something like `logger.exception("Could not load preferences", e)` (where `logger` is an instance created with the Python logging module).

Comment: Doesn't preferences.txt need quote around it?

Comment: @fredrikklj, ...yup, indeed.

Comment: put your file name in quotes, like `open_pre = open("preferences.txt", "r")`

Comment: 2nd issue, you are trying to `close` a string with `open_pre.close()`, you can't do that

Comment: You're reusing the variable `open_pre` -- first it contains the open file, then you replace it with the string you read from the file. So you can't use `open_pre.close()`, because it's not the file any more. Use different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently a few problems in your code (not just a single one)

### Variables vs Strings

You are doing `preferences.txt`which is being read as "The `txt` property of the `preferences` variable". What you want is to have the text treated as a string, so you need to put double quotes around it `"preferences.txt"`.

### Overiding data

You open the file, into a variable called `open_pre`. The value of this variable is what you need to close. However, you override that data when you set it to the value of the file (`open_pre = open_pre.read()`). That means the value of the variable is no longer the file stream that you need to close, but instead the contents of the file. You cannot close a string, only a file, so after the first error you will get a second one. Instead, don't override the file when reading it.

### Hiding errors

The fact that you used a `try`/`except` clause meant that you could not have an error message that had all the error information. While debugging, remember that unfriendly error messages are better than vague, but readable, outputs. Better practice (which would help you find the first error), is to specify which error you are looking for so that other errors get caught using unfriendly errors.

### To summarise

The correct code would look like this, fixing all the errors above.

```
try:
    open_pre = open("preferences.txt", "r") # Change to quotes
    contents = open_pre.read() # Use separate variable
    open_pre.close() # So that you can close the file stream, not the content string.
    print(contents)
except IOError: # Be more specific on which errors to ignore
    print("Could not load preferences.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is the actual code block you are using, something very obvious is going wrong: you are getting a `NameError`:

```
>>> open(data.html, 'r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Why? `preferences.txt` is treated as a *variable*, not a string. It should be `'preferences.txt'`.

It is a very bad idea to swallow all exceptions with an indiscriminate `except` block. You should only catch *specific exceptions* that you know how to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should be doing:

```
open_pre = open('preferences.txt', "r") # file name is a string

file_var = '' # store file in string variable
for line in open_pre:
    file_var += line
```